# Java SimpleDateFormat Seemingly Ignoring Month and Day

Tags: java

I have this piece of simple code:

```
SimpleDateFormat sqlFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat ("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String temp = "2012-03-09 12:00:00";
System.out.println (temp);
Date last = sqlFormatter.parse (temp);
System.out.println (last);
```

I get this output:

```
2012-03-09 12:00:00
Sun Jan 01 12:00:00 EST 2012
```

I know is supposed to be simple, but I am hoping someone can quickly see what I am missing.

Comment: I notice that you write `new SimpleDateFormatter(...)` rather than `new SimpleDateFormat(...)`. Is that intentional? If so, is it possible that the `SimpleDateFormatter` class does something you're not aware of that affects this parsing?

Comment: Do you mean `SimpleDateFormat` instead of `SimpleDateFormatter`?

Comment: No, not intentional, just a typo, thank you.

Comment: Now that you've fixed that, your code gives me `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'Y'`, because `SimpleDateFormat` uses `yyyy` for year, not `YYYY`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your pattern is a little off.  I'm suprised you're not seeing an IllegalArgumentException.  Try using the following pattern with lower case y's and see if that resolves your issue:

```
SimpleDateFormat sqlFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 2):

Corrected code here:

`SimpleDateFormat sqlFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String temp = "2012-03-09 12:00:00";
        System.out.println(temp);
        Date last = sqlFormatter.parse(temp);
        System.out.println(last);`

You should have `SimpleDateFormat` instead of `SimpleDateFormatter` and for years you give `yyyy` instead of `YYYY`.

Answer (score 1):

Once I corrected your format String - `Y` is not allowed, you need `y` - (and the typo already mentioned) it worked fine:

```
SimpleDateFormat sqlFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String temp = "2012-03-09 12:00:00";
System.out.println (temp);
Date last = sqlFormatter.parse (temp);
System.out.println (last);

>2012-03-09 12:00:00
>Fri Mar 09 12:00:00 EST 2012
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use 'yyyy' and not 'YYYY'

Here is the output

```
2012-03-09 12:00:00
Fri Mar 09 12:00:00 IST 2012
```

for the pattern

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```